# Query to get specific properties of object in array in documentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a list of documents in the documentDB. Each document is a JSON object like below:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "field1": "property1" 
    "field2": {[ 
                    {
                        "a": "A",
                        "b": "B",
                        "c": "C",
                        "d": "D"
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "E",
                        "b": "F",
                        "c": "G",
                        "d": "H"
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "I",
                        "b": "J",
                        "c": "K",
                        "d": "L"
                    }   
              ]}
}
```

I want to get all objects with all fields except for "c" and "d" in field2. The result should be like below:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "field1": "property1" 
    "field2": {[ 
                    {
                        "a": "A",
                        "b": "B",
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "E",
                        "b": "F",
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "I",
                        "b": "J"
                    }   
              ]}
}
```

What is the correct query for this problem? The challenge for me here is how to iterate through each nested object in array in field2 and extract only "a" and "b". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove specific fields in source data, I suggest you using [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs) to achieve your requirements. You could refer to below test steps, it works.

***sample documents:***

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "field1": "property1",
        "field2": [
            {
                "a": "A",
                "b": "B",
                "c": "C",
                "d": "D"
            },
            {
                "a": "E",
                "b": "F",
                "c": "G",
                "d": "H"
            },
            {
                "a": "I",
                "b": "J",
                "c": "K",
                "d": "L"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "field1": "property2",
        "field2": [
            {
                "a": "A",
                "b": "B",
                "c": "C",
                "d": "D"
            },
            {
                "a": "E",
                "b": "F",
                "c": "G",
                "d": "H"
            },
            {
                "a": "I",
                "b": "J",
                "c": "K",
                "d": "L"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

***stored procedure code:***

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT r.id,r.field1,r.field2 FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var returnArray=[];
            for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
                var array = [];
                for(var j=0;j<feed[i].field2.length;j++){
                    console.log(j)

                    var obj = feed[i].field2[j];
                    var objNew = {};
                    for(var key in obj){
                        if(key != "c" && key !="d"){
                            console.log(obj[key]);
                            objNew[key] = obj[key];
                        }
                    }
                    array.push(objNew);
                }
                feed[i].field2 = array;
            }

            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

***Output:***

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "field1": "property1",
        "field2": [
            {
                "a": "A",
                "b": "B"
            },
            {
                "a": "E",
                "b": "F"
            },
            {
                "a": "I",
                "b": "J"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "field1": "property2",
        "field2": [
            {
                "a": "A",
                "b": "B"
            },
            {
                "a": "E",
                "b": "F"
            },
            {
                "a": "I",
                "b": "J"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like 'select d.id, d.field1, getNewField2(d.field2) from XXX' where getNewField2(d.field2) is part of the query?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT f.id, f.field1, ARRAY(select c.a, c.b from c in f.field2) as field2
FROM f
```

Comment: Please add an explanation and proper syntax highliting to your answer. It has already been flagged as "low quality" and is in risk of deletion.